# Dark mode of Azure Data Factory UI

Tags: azure-data-factory, darkmode, dark-theme

Can we enable dark mode/ dark theme for ADF UI?

Seems there is no built-in settings.

Answer (score 3):

Currently, there is no built-in support, but you can check whether below options can help:

1. Edge and Chrome have a preview feature.

Edge:
[image]

Chrome:
[image]

2. Browser extensions, like dark reader
   [image]
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

ADF now supports Dark mode natively.
[image]